# Android camera image orientation without sufaceView

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I am having a service in which I have to capture image without a surfaceView, everything is working perfect except the result image orientation, which I found to be miss-angled. On small device like HTC, I found it having issue or rotation so set rotation manually to see it working and it worked.

```
if (camInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    parameters.setRotation(270);
 } else if (camInfo.facing ==
    Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
    parameters.setRotation(90);
 }
```

But when checking over samsung and HTC one (large devices) it creates problem with the angle. I found some posts where there I have to put the image path and then try to set the rotation, but that didn't work for me i.e. this as I am taking picture without serfaceview and then immediately posting it to the server. I also tried the google portion of code for setCameraOrientation() but it requires the activity view to work and so I am failed there too.

All I need is to fix the angle of the image before sent to the server without any surfaceview or activity thing.

Answer (score 0):

`setRotation()` may only choose to play with the EXIF flags. The result is an image which is still rotated 90°, but with a "flag" that describes the correct orientation. Not all viewers correctly account for this flag. Specifically, `BitmapFactory` ignores it. You can draw the bitmap rotated on a canvas, or rotate the bitmap acquired from `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`, or manipulate the JPEG data before writing it into outStream using a 3<sup>rd</sup> party lib, e.g. [MediaUtil](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/javadocs/mediautil/image/jpeg/LLJTran.html). The Android port is on [GitHub](http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil).

Answer (score 0):

You can have access to the image orientation information through the ExifInterface object. It will give you different values depending on the phone and if you capture the image in Landscape or Portrait mode. You can then use a matrix to rotate the image according to the ExifInterface information.And finally send it to your server.

Knowing the path of your image ( imagePath ), use the following code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();   
try{            
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    // Change the image orientation
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    // Change the image orientation
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    break;
}catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Then you use your matrix object in order to rotate your bitmap using:

```
  rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),matrix, true);
```

You would have to save the bitmap somewhere ( external or internal temp storage ) before sending it to the server.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't want to save that anywhere. I guess for that i would need it to clear later on, because as I said it's a non activity background running service to get the image so a kind of non=visible thing

Answer (score 0):

Your rotation-setting code is a bit too simple, so it's possible that on some devices it'll do the wrong thing.  It's not guaranteed that these are the right rotations - the correct answer is a function of your device's current orientation, and the orientation of the sensor on the device.

Take a look at the sample code for [Camera.Parameters.setRotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29):

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
  if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
  android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
        new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
  android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
  orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
  int rotation = 0;
  if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
     rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
  } else {  // back-facing camera
     rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
  }
  mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

If you don't have an activity, you'll have to figure out how to get the device's current orientation some other way, but you do need to include `info.orientation` in your calculation.

Comment: yes that's the point that I don't have an activity, for the activity thing I have somewhat success of code there!